Zitadel Go via Nginx
We have a self hosted Zitadel instance which is only available internally, let's say on ip 1.1.1.1:443.
We have another machine, that is available over the internet let's say on https://foo.bar and it hosts an application, which I am trying to connect to my zitadel instance and utilize its authentication workflow. I've tried to set it up with nginx, as to pass foo.bar/zitadel to 1.1.1.1:443
So here's my code:
const Domain = "1.1.1.1:443"
const Key = "12345678901234567890123456789012"
const ClientID = "123456789@foo"
const RedirectURI = "https://foo.bar/auth/callback"

type ConfigZitadel struct {
    AuthN *authentication.Authenticator[*openid.UserInfoContext[*oidc.IDTokenClaims, *oidc.UserInfo]]
    Mw   *authentication.Interceptor[*openid.UserInfoContext[*oidc.IDTokenClaims, *oidc.UserInfo]]
}

func NewConfigZitadel() (*ConfigZitadel, error) {
    config_zitadel := &ConfigZitadel{}
    ctx := context.Background()
    authN, err := authentication.New(ctx, zitadel.New(Domain), Key,
        openid.DefaultAuthentication(ClientID, RedirectURI, Key),
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("zitadel sdk could not initialize", "error", err)
        return nil, err
    }
    mw := authentication.Middleware(authN)
    config_zitadel.AuthN = authN
    config_zitadel.Mw = mw
    return config_zitadel, nil

}

It can connect to my instance, however the auth workflow will not work as /auth/login will try to redirect me to 1.1.1.1, but setting it to foo.bar/zitadel also wont work, because it throws an error that Issuer does not match.
Is what I'm trying to do achievable somehow?
Or must the Zitadel instance be publicly available in a way?
